# ARPlaneAnchor's 'extent' property deprecated

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, aranchor

I'm using ARKit to build an AR app with SceneKit. When I was creating an SCNPlane object when SceneKit detected a horizontal plane using ARPlaneAnchor's `extent` of `x` and `y` properties I ran into this warning:

```
// *'extent' was deprecated in iOS 16*
```

My sample code is below:

```
let planeAnchor = anchor as! ARPlaneAnchor

let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x), 
                    height: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z))
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [planeExtent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arplaneextent) property instead, with `width`, `height` & `rotationOnYAxis` sub-properties.

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
open var planeExtent: ARPlaneExtent { get }
```

In iOS 16.0 and higher, `extend` property is deprecated:

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 11.0, deprecated: 16.0)
open var extent: simd_float3 { get }
```